# Start python-code as a Daemon with daemon-tools from Bernstein

Tags: python, daemon

I'm trying to start a daemon with daemon-tools from bernstein. With normaly shell it works very well but how can i start a simply python code as daemon with daemon tools? for example something simple like this.

```
def run(name):
  while name:
    print("Hello"+name)
    return "whoooheee"
```

this should be a daemon that runs in background and if it gets a call like

```
result = run.run("Bob")
```

from another programm it should print Hello and return a result to that programm.

Is this possible with daemon-tools from bernstein ?

thank you.

and yes it has to be daemon-tools :)